# ASP MVC - Bunch of random characters in POST request route string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I am trying to log in to my own application, and i have discovered something strange. When I am sending a POST request to a login controller, it somehow redirects itself to a GET login controller, and displays login form with an action set to `http://localhost:5898/(X(1)S(1tgv3m2psb2cxqaw4koiyhyt))/Account/Login`. Now what the hell is this `(X(1)S(1tgv3m2psb2cxqaw4koiyhyt))` thing? Why is it there, and what does it do? And on top of that, how do i get rid of it? I do not want it in there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you have set the session provider in your web.config (or on IIS) to use a Cookieless session state.  This is the session identifier for your session.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic2

To get rid of it, you would need to change your `sessionState` element in your web.config to `cookieless="false"`

[SessionState Web.Config element information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Those things are seen in asp.net when you disable cookie in your browser or your application settings. that is cookieless asp.net. you can start debugging your app from there.
hope it helps